# Webpack WordPress image underlining upload folder

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, optimization, webpack

I have a custom built WP theme, however the blog (apart from some styling) is standard.
My problem is when people add images to the blog they upload via WP CMS and the images go into the upload folder.

I have web pack setup in my theme and I optimise images in my theme using imagemin plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webpack

problem is it only runs on images within my theme, how can i expand to optimise all images in the upload folder in WP ?

**My webpack**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractWebpackPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const NonJsEntryCleanupPlugin = require('./non-js-entry-cleanup-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const {context, entry, devtool, outputFolder, publicFolder} = require('./config');
const HMR = require('./hmr');
const getPublicPath = require('./publicPath');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;

module.exports = (options) => {
    const {dev} = options;
    const hmr = HMR.getClient();

    return {
        mode: dev ? 'development' : 'production',
        devtool: dev ? devtool : false,
        context: path.resolve(context),
        entry: {
            'styles/main': dev ? [hmr, entry.styles] : entry.styles,
            'scripts/main': dev ? [hmr, entry.scripts] : entry.scripts,
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(outputFolder),
            publicPath: getPublicPath(publicFolder),
            filename: '[name].[Chunkhash].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)\/(?!(dom7|ssr-window|swiper)\/).*/,
                    use: [
                        ...(dev ? [{loader: 'cache-loader'}] : []),
                        {loader: 'babel-loader'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        ...(dev ? [{loader: 'cache-loader'}, {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                            options: {sourceMap: dev}
                        }] : [MiniCssExtractWebpackPlugin.loader]),
                        {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: dev}},
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {
                                ident: 'postcss',
                                sourceMap: dev,
                                config: {ctx: {dev}}
                            }
                        },
                        {loader: 'resolve-url-loader', options: {sourceMap: dev}},
                        {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true, sourceMapContents: dev}},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpe?g|gif|ico|mp4|webm)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: 'svg/[name].[ext]',
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'svgo-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: [
                                    { removeTitle: true },
                                    { convertColors: { shorthex: false } },
                                    { convertPathData: false },
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff2?)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            ...(dev ? [
                new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin()
            ] : [
                new MiniCssExtractWebpackPlugin({
                    filename: '[name].[Chunkhash].css'
                }),
                new NonJsEntryCleanupPlugin({
                    context: 'styles',
                    extensions: 'js',
                    includeSubfolders: true
                }),
                new CleanWebpackPlugin([
                    path.resolve(outputFolder)
                ], {
                    allowExternal: true,
                    beforeEmit: true
                }),
                new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                    {
                        from: path.resolve(`${context}/**/*`),
                        to: path.resolve(outputFolder),
                    }
                ], {
                    ignore: ['*.js', '*.ts', '*.scss', '*.css']
                }),
                new ImageminPlugin({
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                    cacheFolder: './imgcache',
                    pngquant: {
                        quality: '95-100'
                    }
                })
            ])
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: There are several ways, you can install the wordpress plugin, or do it using the command line nodejs, of course, if you have access to the server.
In wordpress, e.g., [wp-smushit](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)
or in the node library which is called [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp)

Comment: wp-smushit, perfect ill look into this thanks